# Closed testing getting item not found

Tags: android, testing, google-play-console

I have an app that I want to test with a google group of testers. I have all of this set up, enabled any domain etc.. I waited a week for the app to be published (it is now published), shared the opt-in link with the google group but after opting in testers are unable to view the app - it just says 'item not found', despite their devices (and over 8000 more) being supported. I tried waiting for another 3 days but nothing has changed. The testing devices all have a sole google account.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is, either the app isn't published, its actually in draft (you shouldn't have to wait a week for an app to be published - usually a few hours at most). Or there's devices which your app doesn't support and people are using those unsupported devices. You can check on the play store the supported/unsupported devices for your app.

Comment: Please confirm your app is published or pending.

Comment: My app is published, and when looking at the supported devices, google pixel (what I am testing this on) is supported, along with over 8000 other devices.

Comment: @Boardy the link opens the play store page when opened in a browser on my macbook, however the link doesn't work when opened on the pixel - any ideas?

Comment: Hmm strange, I'm afraid I haven't got any ideas other than trying to ask Google, if you can find a way to contact them, they don't make it easy unfortunately